# Determining if a block has any content when passed to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= render :layout => "some_layout" do %>
  <p>Some stuff</p>
<% end %>
```

In "some_layout"

```
<%= yield %>
```

Is there a way to detect if the yield block has any content? Example:

```
<% if block_has_content? %>
   <%= yield %>
<% else %>
  <p>Default content</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look to this documentation: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

You can define somewhere:

```
 <% content_for :some_layout do %>
     some content
 <% end %>
```

And in an other part of your code:

```
<%= content_for(:some_layout) || 'Default content' %>
```

If content for :some_layout is not defined, it will take the default one.

Comment: I can't use content_for I am using the layout to pass blocks to a partial.